# sony small app with fix window

Tags: android, sony-xperia

I am working with Sony's smapp app and I want my window to be fixed or not resizable. need your help guys. Thanks..

```
    setMinimizedView(R.layout.main_minimized);

    setTitle(R.string.small_app_name);

    SmallAppWindow.Attributes attr = getWindow().getAttributes();


    attr.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_width);
    attr.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_height);
    attr.flags |= SmallAppWindow.Attributes.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;

    getWindow().setAttributes(attr);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three flags you can set:

**FLAG_NO_TITLEBAR,
FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
FLAG_RESIZABLE**

By default the resizable flag is true.
This code will disable all flags:

```
attr.flags = 0;
```

It looks like you want hardware acceleration though so do the following to only have hardware acceleration:

```
attr.flags = 0;
attr.flags |= SmallAppWindow.Attributes.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;
```

Comment: Thanks! now i figured it out... it is now working. :)